# CSS - height:calc(100% - Nem) doesn't work when it is inside flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three rows : fixed, fluid, fixed. These three rows are together 100% height and must be always visible on page without scrolling. In fluid row I have module that must take 100% height of it. Besides in module I need to use overflow:auto.
This is my code:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }
    
    .flexbox-parent
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
    }
    
    .flexbox-item-grow
    {
        flex: 1;
    }
    
    .fill-area
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: stretch; 
        align-content: stretch;
        
    }
    
    div.module {
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       background-color:yellow;
    }
    
    div.scrolling {
        height:calc(100% - 4em);
        overflow:auto;
    }
    
    div.header, div.footer {
      height: 2em;
      background:cyan;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flexbox-parent">
        <div>
            TOP
        </div>
        <div class="fill-area flexbox-item-grow">
            <div class="flexbox-item-grow">
       <div class="module">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="scrolling">
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
            <p> Some Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
       </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            BOTTOM
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pavel_K/nvvnb3po/). Please, who knows, help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overflow: auto` on scrolling element but you also need to add `overflow: hidden` on previous parent elements and you need to use `flex: 1` also.

```css
* {
  /* So 100% means 100% */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flexbox-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.flexbox-item-grow, .module{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scrolling {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
.header,
.footer {
  background: cyan;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div>
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="fill-area flexbox-item-grow">
    <div class="flexbox-item-grow">
      <div class="module">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="scrolling">
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
          <p> Some Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    BOTTOM
  </div>
</div>
```